# If $\sum \frac{1}{\vert a_{n} \vert}$ converges then $\sum \frac{1}{\vert a_{n} - m\vert}$ also converges.($m \in R$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was trying to prove that if $\sum \frac{1}{\vert a_{n} \vert}$ converges then $\sum \frac{1}{x - a_{n}}$ also converges, and after some work I found out that if I prove that if $\sum \frac{1}{\vert a_{n}-m \vert}: m \in \mathbb{R}$ converges,  I solve the problem, but I've been trying a lot of ways and I couldnt't prove anything.

Comment: You should probably restrict $m$ to $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$. Otherwise you run the risk of dividing by $0$ somewhere in the sum.

Comment: $$\frac1{a_n-x}=\frac1{a_n}\left(1-\frac x{a_n}\right)^{-1}=\frac1{a_n}+O\left(\frac1{a_n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the limit comparison test.

Namely,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/|a_n|}{1/|a_n-m|} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n-m|}{|a_n|} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left| 1-\frac{m}{a_n}
 \right| = 1$$
because the general term of a convergent series converges to $0$.

Of course, you need to consider where the terms are defined (i.e. avoid dividing by zero).

Answer (score 1):

$||a_n|-|m||\le |a_n-m|$ .

$\dfrac{1}{|a_n-m|} \le \dfrac{1}{||a_n|-|m||}$.

Let $n_0$ large enough, then for $n \ge n_0$:

$|a_n|>2|m|$:

$\dfrac{1}{|a_n-m|} \lt \dfrac{1}{||a_n|-|m||} \lt$

$\dfrac{1}{(1/2)|a_n|}=\dfrac{2}{|a_n|}$.

Comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum \frac{1}{|a_n|}$ converges, there is some $N$ such that for all $n\geqslant N$, we have $|a_n|>2|x|$, if and only if $|a_n| - |x|>|a_n|/2$. Thus, for all $n\geqslant N$,
$$
\frac{1}{|a_n-x|}\leqslant\frac{1}{|a_n|-|x|} <\frac{2}{|a_n|},
$$
so the series $\sum\frac{1}{|a_n-x|}$ converges by direct comparison with $\sum\frac{2}{|a_n|}$.